# Here Maps not showing in Ionic tabs

Tags: ionic-framework, tabs, here-api

I have a quite basic Here Map in an Ionic tap that is loaded in a Ionic tab with this JavaScript.

```
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
    useCIT: true,
    'app_id': $(component).data('appid'),
    'app_code': $(component).data('appcode'),
    useHTTPS: true
    });

    // Obtain the default map types from the platform object
    var maptypes = platform.createDefaultLayers();

    // Instantiate (and display) a map object:
    var map = new H.Map(
    document.getElementById('mapContainer'),
    maptypes.normal.map,
    {
      zoom: 10,
      center: { lng: $(component).data('long'),
                lat: $(component).data('lat')
              }
    });

// Enable the event system on the map instance:
var mapEvents = new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map);

// Add event listeners:
map.addEventListener('tap', function(evt) {
  // Log 'tap' and 'mouse' events:
  console.log(evt.type, evt.currentPointer.type);
```

When adding this not in tab 1 the map is not showing. I tried and searched for several things but they only are for Google Maps. How can i get this working in the Ionic tabs?

Comment: The above code for initializing the map is fine in itself. Are you able to see any error in the log? I'd check first and foremost that the `mapContainer` element is in the DOM of the tab view when the map is initialized. Then, check that the dynamic data is correctly retrieved.

Comment: It appears that there's a familiar problem with showing Google Maps in a tab eventually I found a workaround with an event trigger when the Map tab opens.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with following code snippet :

```js
function moveMapToBerlin(map){
  map.setCenter({lat:52.5159, lng:13.3777});
  map.setZoom(14);
}

/**
 * Boilerplate map initialization code starts below:
 */

//Step 1: initialize communication with the platform
// In your own code, replace variable window.apikey with your own apikey
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
  apikey: window.apikey
});
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

//Step 2: initialize a map - this map is centered over Europe
var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
  defaultLayers.vector.normal.map,{
  center: {lat:50, lng:5},
  zoom: 4,
  pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
});
// add a resize listener to make sure that the map occupies the whole container
window.addEventListener('resize', () => map.getViewPort().resize());

//Step 3: make the map interactive
// MapEvents enables the event system
// Behavior implements default interactions for pan/zoom (also on mobile touch environments)
var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

// Create the default UI components
var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);

// Now use the map as required...
window.onload = function () {
  moveMapToBerlin(map);
}
```